# Create Columns based on keywords and check if it present or not

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to programming. I faced a issue. I wanted to create columns for keywords and check if the keyword is present in the text column or not if it is present then return keyword in that particular keyword column or else return null values. Can you please help me solve this problem?
[image for list of my keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uFNW.png)

Now I want to create columns that are items of list and check for items present in text if they are present return that item else return null values?

Comment: Share it with an example

Comment: It would be great if you first showed us what you did, what your input looks like and what your output should look like. You can read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to check how to ask a question with a Minimal Workable Example :)

Comment: Check the image and please answer my question

Comment: I wanted to create each item as new column and if the list is present return that item else null values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you probably mean something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'text': ['the quick brown fox', 'jumps over', 'the lazy dog']})

# DataFrame looks like
#                   text
# 0  the quick brown fox
# 1           jumps over
# 2         the lazy dog

# Define keywords
keyword_list = ['the', 'fox', 'dog']

# Function to find keyword in text
def find_keyword(text, keyword):
    if keyword in text:
        return keyword

# Loop over keywords and apply function, then save result in column called like the keyword
for keyword in keyword_list:
    df[keyword] = df['text'].apply(lambda t: find_keyword(t, keyword))


# DataFrame looks like
#                  text   the   fox   dog
# 0  the quick brown fox   the   fox  None
# 1           jumps over  None  None  None
# 2         the lazy dog   the  None   dog
```

Comment: I did this but I am getting type error that is argument of type float is not iterable

Comment: @pavansamanthgoli Sorry but it is really hard to help you out if you don't share your code. Please **edit your question** and try to write down what you did and if you get an error **copy/paste the exact error**. You shouldn't use link to images, but actually write the code in your question itself. [This is a guide to formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and [this is a guide to make your question acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please **read them carefully**.

Comment: Hi @UJIN can you contact me